# How to handle concurrent bids in auction app?

Tags: django

I am studying on starting a new Django project with reverse auctions (countdown timer). Every time a user makes a bid the price increases by a specific amount (eg 0.05$) and the clock resets. If no one bids in the given time the last bidder wins. I am thinking on using AJAX calls in order to update values and avoid page reload.

But what is the best way to handle concurrent bids?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a task queue like Celery: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html or if your app is small you can try: https://github.com/Aviah/django-queue

Comment: Also see https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2